# iTextSharp Resize each page to fit the pagesize

Tags: c#, pdf, split, itext, resize

I have a .pdf document which has for example 7 pages. I split this document into 7 .pdf document, so it means that each document has only one page. But mainly I need to make fit the content of pages. So delete whitespaces, margins, resize. Have you got some simple advice? I add links for images and also code for split pdf document. Thank you for your response.

INPUT:

[image]

DESIRED OUTPUT:

[image]

CODE:

```
        public void PdfSplitDocument(string filename)
    {
        String path = "C:/Doc/" + filename;
        String result = "d:/output/result";
        PdfCopy copy;
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(result + i + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();
            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
            document.Close();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [ShowTextMargins](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=280) example. It uses the [TextMarginFinder](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/TextMarginFinder.html) class to find the margins within which text is found. In this example, taken from my book "iText in Action - Second Edition", I use this class to draw a rectangle:

```
public void addMarginRectangle(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
    TextMarginFinder finder;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        finder = parser.processContent(i, new TextMarginFinder());
        PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(i);
        cb.rectangle(finder.getLlx(), finder.getLly(),
            finder.getWidth(), finder.getHeight());
        cb.stroke();
    }
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

In your case, you want to crop the pages based on the rectangle. You have a `finder` object that allows you to get the coordinate of the lower-left corner (llx and lly) and the coordinate of the upper-right corner (urx and ury). You can use these coordinates to crop pages as is done in the [CropPages](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=231) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfDictionary pageDict;
    PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);
        pageDict.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rect);
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Another option is to change the media box instead of the crop box:

```
pageDict.put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, rect);
```

The C# version of these examples can be found here:

- [ShowTextMargins](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter15/ShowTextMargins.cs)
- [CropPages](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter13/CropPages.cs)